# Does HTMl5 tel and sms return any values?

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, cordova, sencha-touch

I am building a sample html5 application which is targeted to run on Iphone,Ipad,Andriod devices , Application contains a contact us feature where it includes 'tel' and 'sms' functionality , Its works fine if i run the application in Iphone or Andriod phones, The problem with Ipad is it does not support for html5 'tel' or 'sms' , so i am looking for a alternate fix for this , I wanted to know whether the 'tel' or 'sms' tags return any values , based on the return value i can write a function for avoid call and sms functionality for Ipad or Tab devices

Comment: What do you mean "'tel' or 'sms' tags return any values"?  Unsupported `<input>` types should act like plain text input fields if that's what you're asking, but I'm not sure it is.

Comment: Ipad does not contain a direct call and sms functionality , so i am looking for a fix

Comment: What does the browser support for these HTML5 input types have to do with the fact that the iPad cannot make phone calls or send SMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use links like:

```
<a href='callto:12345567890'>Click to call</a>
```

which should work everywhere (including on Android, Desktop browsers etc)

I'm not sure about SMS, as I don't own a phone to test on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,This works on Iphone correctly i have tested , my question is how to make it work for Ipad?

Comment: The iPad can't make calls or send SMS, so in short, you can't as it doesn't offer those features.

Comment: I have built single html5 application which works on Iphone, Ipad , Android devices,If the sms or call feature is not supported in Ipad, I am thinking to make a little diversion of code for Ipad so that it alerts the user when they click on call or sms button saying it does not support this feature

Comment: Why not just not show them, or add some different code on iPads? You can't detect via JS whether it can make calls.

Comment: Ya you are right , its better to hide the call and sms buttons if the device is Ipad , but i think the latest Ipad one with 3G or 4G network enabled supports the call or SMS functionality ,I am confused to diffrentate between the Ipad with 3G enabled and 3G not enabled

Comment: None of them support calls or SMS. The 3G is only for Data, not for calls or SMS messages.